# Angular js bootstrap modal is not scrollable at the lower version of bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap css version v2.2.2 and an older version of bootsrap.js . The bootstrap modal pop up does not scroll instead the background content does. The modal gets cut even in responsive view. Not able to view the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the background attribute (position) of Modal from fixed to absolute in Bootstrap.css.
Or try to use Bootstrap especially for AngularJS: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Cheers